# Disable Enchanced authentication options in Direct line connection channel of azure bot via powershell command?

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-devops, azure-bot-service

How can I disable **enchanced authentication options** in **direct line connection** channel of azure bot via powershell command?

Answer (score 0):

There are not any powershell (*-azbot*) cmdlets to do so that I am aware of. But you can do it via AZ CLI (within PowerShell or CMD) by doing:

`az bot directline update --enable-enhanced-auth false --name <BOTNAME> --resource-group <RESOURCEGROUP>`